# How to get scanf to only accept integers?

Tags: c, input, scanf

i'm new at c and i was wondering if something like this is possible,

i'm trying to write an input like a coordinate. The user would enter a coordinate like (3,4) and the program would scan the input as 3 & 4 both recorded in the variable cor1, cor2 respectively.

I am trying for an output like this:

```
Enter coordinates: (3,4)

3 4                           /*printf("%d %d",cor1,cor2)*/
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look to `scanf` function, especially `%d` format.

Comment: if the format for the scanf is to an int, characters will fail and scanf will return an error. do some coding and try things out.

Comment: If you want the user to enter his input as (x,y), you can simply scan the whole line "(3,4)" and then using a loop and few lines of code you can extract the two coordinates. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

scanf is definitely the answer here:

```
int cor1,cor2;
int num_parsed = scanf("(%d,%d)",&cor1,&cor2);
if(num_parsed != 2)
    printf("Failed to parse coords!\n");
else
    printf("%d %d",cor1,cor2);
```

Take a go at that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is possible.

Use the same format specifiers as you do by the call to `printf()` for `scanf()` and place the `,` (comma) between both format specifiers:

```
printf("Enter coordinates: ");

scanf("%d,%d", &cor1, &cor2);
```

Note that you need to precede the objects to store the decimal values by the `&` ampersand operator to gather the address of the according objects, which is different to the `printf()` call and required by `scanf()`.

Also always check the return value of `scanf()` if an error occurred at scanning:

```
if(scanf("%d,%d", &cor1, &cor2) != 2)
{
     print("Error at scanning!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` function scans input from the console. In order to get inputs from the console, you need to specify what type of inputs you want to get. For `int` values, we use the `%d` format specifier to indicate that we will be entering `int` value as our input.
Now answering your question: How do you want to read the inputs from the user? Should the user input just `3 4` or `(3,4)`? Let's discuss each of the scenarios:

- Case 1

Here the user will input `3 4`.

```
int cor1, cor2;
printf("Enter coordinates: ");
scanf("%d %d", &cor1, &cor2);
printf("%d %d", cor1, cor2);
```

- Case 2

Here the user will input `(3,4)`. Before I type the code, notice that there are 3 redundant `char` values: `( , )`. We need to discard those characters from our input. As you know, we use `%c` to input a `char` value from the console. In order to discard those redundant characters, we simply use the `%*c` format specifier.

```
int cor1, cor2, valueInput;
printf("Enter coordinates: ");

valueInput=scanf("%*c %d %*c %d %*c", &cor1, &cor2);
if(valueInput==2){
    printf("%d %d", cor1, cor2);
}else{
    printf("Failed to parse inputs");
}
```

This will allow you to input `(3,4)` and output `3 4`. To add an extra check, we also check the `return` value of `scanf()`. If you aren't familiar with a `return` value, then take a look at: [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-statement-in-c-cpp-with-examples/). The `scanf()` function returns the number of successful inputs. As an extra check, we also check the `return` value of `scanf()`. In the first case, I skipped the check so that you don't get confused. For more information, take a look at:
Format Specifiers:  [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/format-specifiers/)
Formatted I/O: [overiq](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/formatted-input-and-output-in-c/)